# Installing C++ on eclipse under one condition

Tags: c++, eclipse

What if you have the Eclipse IDE already installed on your computer, but the condition is that you have the JAVA eclipse installed but you also want to add the C++ Eclipse feature to your existing Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Just install the Eclipse CDT (C/C++ Developer Tools) plugin. Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you install the eclipse CDT plugin?

Comment: Try the answer I just posted.

Comment: Okay. So I need to install another separate eclipse with the CDT plugin?

Comment: No, you install the CDT plugin into your existing Eclipse installation. It will add another perspective for working with C and C++ development.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, select:
    Help -> Install new software

In the Install dialog, under "Work with:" select Mars - http://download.eclipse.org/release/mars (or whatever Eclipse version you're on)

Then select:
    Programming Languages -> C/C++ Development Tools

Select "Next >" and continue through the remaining questions. Restart Eclipse and you should have CDT installed.

Comment: I tried installing the "Mars - http://download.eclipse.org/release/mars"  and when I tried to add the website for the plugin I get this message:

"Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/release/mars/content.xml."

Comment: @JanePoe: Is your Eclipse version Mars?

Comment: No it is eclipse kepler apparently

Comment: Then use the update site for Kepler: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/

Comment: Thank you. Ill try that one